# Nested Models in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have the following Models:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :name, :post_id
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic,    :touch => true
  has_many   :comments, :dependent => destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic, :comments
  attr_accessible :name, :title, :content, :topic, :topic_attributes
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Post
end
```

Is this simple form valid? Can I access 2 nested Models at the same time?

```
simple_form_for @post do |f|
  f.simple_fields_for :topic do |topic_form|
    topic_form.input :name
  end
  f.simple_fields_for :comment do |comment_form|
    comment_form.input :text
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about the simple_fields plugin but using accepts_nested_attributes_for and rails' regular fields_for you can nest form data as you describe. As it happens there are a bunch of questions about said plugin which you can explore by clicking on the tag I added to your question.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. Is it not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
simple_form_for @post do |f|
  f.simple_fields_for @post.topic do |topic_form|
    topic_form.input :name
  end
  f.simple_fields_for @post.comments do |comment_form|
    comment_form.input :text
  end
end
```